# CSS align rotated text

Tags: css, rotation, right-align

I have a rotated text within a div. I want to align the span to the "right" (see red arrow) of the div

```
<div class="rotateText">
  <span>This is a rotated multiline text please display it in a correct way. This is a rotated multiline text please display it in a correct way</span>
</div>

    .rotateText{
      width: 200px;
      height: 300px;
      writing-mode: tb-rl;
      transform: rotate(-180deg);
      background-color: yellow;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/konqmr8c/1/

[image]

Comment: Do you want the text to align to the right, or do you want the box rotated the other way so the bottom of the text faces left?

Comment: `padding: 1rem 4rem 1rem 0;` works too (or just `padding-right: 4rem`)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple way to do this would be with `position: absolute`. Apply `relative` to the parent container so you can anchor the span to it, and then set `left: 0`. This will make the text hug the bottom of the container.

```
.rotateText{
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

This will result in this:

[image: Rotated]

If you want to just rotate the entire box just remove the `transform` property. Resulting in:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might not need an extra container , `flex`, `writing-mode` and `align-items` should do. `writing-mode:sideways-lr` missing for some browsers will require transform to reset it on the opposite side.

```css
.rotateText {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellow;
  align-items: flex-end;
  /* 
  writing-mode:sideways-lr; 
 ... would be great if that worked everywhere ,
 let's use what's avalaible and transform :*/
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  transform: scale(-1)
}

.rotateText.column {
  /* if a few child, you need to reset direction and alignement */
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: start
}


/* demo purpose */

.rotateText {
  float: left;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

h1,
p {
  margin: 0.15em;
}
```

```html
<div class="rotateText">
  This is a rotated multiline text please display it in a correct way. This is a rotated multiline text please display it in a correct way
</div>

<div class="rotateText column">
  <h1>Title prior text</h1>
  <p>This is a rotated multiline text please display it in a correct way. This is a rotated multiline text please display it in a correct way </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.rotateText{
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  background-color: yellow;
  position:relative;
}

span {
  border:1px solid red;
  position:absolute;
  left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Flexbox can do that:

Note that the `writing-mode` and `transform` should be on the **child** and not the parent.

```css
.rotateText {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellow;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

span {
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="rotateText">
  <span>This is a rotated multiline text please display it in a correct way. This is a rotated multiline text please display it in a correct way</span>
</div>
```